# IE7: Customizing pop-up background color when opened as a new tab

Tags: javascript, popup, internet-explorer-7

I have a pop-up on my page that I want to have a white background if it's opened as a new tab in IE7. IE7 has a user setting that controls whether pop-ups are opened in a new tab, or otherwise.

Is it possible to customize this? or am I stuck with a black background?

Also, can I set the position of the pop-up if it is opened in a new tab? For instance, if the pop-up was opened as a new tab, I would like for it to be centered on the page with a white background.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read the user's settings - that's a serious security violation and browsers deliberately prevent access to this information.